# PHP prepared statement error: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param():

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm learning to use prepared statements to select all my data from the table in my database however i am getting this error

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match 
number of parameters in prepared statement in 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/contenteditable/classes/class.Insert.inc on 
line 13
```

Perhaps I'm not using the prepared statements in the right way I'm not sure, I have used prepared statements before so hopefully somebody could tell me where Im going wrong or if anyone has a working example that would be helpful.

This is my code:

index.php

```
<div id="maincontent" contenteditable="true">
    <?php
        //get data from database.
        require("classes/class.Insert.inc");
        $insert = new Insert();
        $insert->read();
     ?>

    <button id="save">Save</button>
        <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear changes" />

    </div>
```

classes/class.Insert.php

```
<?php 
include("connect/class.Database.inc");

 class Insert extends Database {

    public $firstname;
    public $content;

public function read(){

    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM datadump');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $content);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $content;      }
        }           
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind_param` binds *parameters* for your query, which has zero placeholders. This causes PHP to complain.

You probably meant to use [`bind_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) instead, which is the way to export result set data into variables.

Comment: When i change this to `bind_result` i get the following error `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/contenteditable/classes/class.Insert.inc on line 13` @Jon

Comment: @gutigrewal: Did you read the manual for `bind_result`? It does not take an `'s'` argument because that would not make any sense (the database already knows the data type of the column). It should not be surprising that blindly substituting the name of one function with that of another does not magically make things work.

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/contenteditable/classes/class.Insert.inc on line 15` now I get this error when i take out the `s` @jon

Comment: @gutigrewal: Yeah, because you are selecting all the columns in your SQL query with `*` and binding only one. If you don't want anything else then `SELECT` just one column. The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: i've updated it to all fields in the database, however with the code above in index.php it is not echoing my data, am i not calling on the function correctly? i have no error message so i assume it is ok i tried echo $content; in index.php but i got a undefined variable @jon

Comment: @gutigrewal: Your result fetching code is incorrect, basically you should be calling [`fetch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) but you are doing other things. Please read the first code example given for `bind_result`, everything you have asked so far is explained fully in the manual. You can read it over there, there's no need to copy/paste it here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35675/discussion-between-gutigrewal-and-jon)